# Android - Gradle sync failed: org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModelorg/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModel

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

Yesterday, without any reason, my Android Studio starts to show the following message:

```
Gradle sync failed: org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModelorg/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModel
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2 s 227 ms)
```

But I not even using Kotlin! Those are my gradle files:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to

```
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        // Firebase import
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // Stupid kotlin build-in plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    testOptions  {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.olegario.escamboapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Scroll view
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    // Firebase database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    // Firebase storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    // Firebase authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

    // Mask
    implementation 'com.vicmikhailau:MaskedEditText:2.0.4'

    // test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'

    // Framework
    implementation project(':capuccino')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Why this is happening? I updated my Android Studio yesterday too, to the version 3.4, but this error started to appear after hours of the update, so I'm assuming that the update has nothing to do with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days, the error simply disappear from my IDE. I believe was some kind of bug in the last update.

Comment: I wish that would happen to me too!

Answer (score 18):

**Upgrade your Kotlin plugin.**

The simple way (Recommended).

`Double shift -> Plugins -> Updates -> search Kotlin -> Update! -> Restart AS`

*Manually way (If you need).*

*1) Download Kotlin Plugin manually from [this link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions).*

*2) Double shift -> Plugins -> (Settings) Icon -> Install from disk -> Choose that plugin.*

*3) Restart.*

Comment: None of this answers will be accepted because, as explained in my topic, I didn't have the Kotlin plugin installed on my Android Studio.

Comment: @olegario, I had the same error and even though I wasn't using Kotlin in my project, I still had to install and enable the Kotlin plugin to fix the build error.

Comment: In my case I removed the plugin since I wasn't using it on the current project and Restart AS .. and it worked well.

Answer (score 6):

If you can't update it, you can just disable it like this:
Double shift -> Plugins -> installed -> search Kotlin -> right click -> Disable -> OK
reopen this dialog again:
Double shift -> Plugins -> installed -> search Kotlin -> right click -> Enable -> OK -> Restart IDE
And it'd done.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks "Salam Hiyali" your answer saved me from reinstalling the Android Studio all over again...

A little modification in the answer given by

> Salam Hiyali
>
> Double shift -> Plugins -> Install JetBrains plugin... --> search Kotlin -> Update! -> Restart AS

Comment: In my case I removed the plugin since I wasn't using it on the current project and Restart AS .. and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to update the `distributionUrl` in the gradle-wrapper.properties files, with the latest available [in official gradle website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html) :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue after upgrading to the Kotlin 1.4 plugin. I found a workaround for this, that should work for all these scenarious.

Add the `idea` plugin to the `build.gradle.kts` file. Then close IntelliJ and manually run `gradle openIdea` This will open the project in idea, forcing the correct configuration to be used.

Unfortunately, it does not fix the use of the sync button.